# How to include a scss file global in my Angular app with webpack?

Tags: angularjs, sass, webpack

I have an Angular application with Webpack and also an application.scss file with the global styles for my application.

What's the best way to include this file in my application so that all components can use styles defined there?

I can´t include the scss file as a link in the index.html as only css files are accepted, so what is the best option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got a configuration working for this.

As I'm talking about a scss file I can´t just import it in my index.html and because I'm using webpack I have to explicitly import it somewhere for this to work, so what I do is import it in my main.ts

```
import './stylesheets/application.sass';
```

Then I just need to configure webpack to process these type of files (which is something I already do when using webpack with Angular); so I'm using this rule in my webpack configuration file

```
{
        test: /\.sass$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/stylesheets'),
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
```

And that's it. All working.